# how to use shall_exec function for long time taking function execution

Tags: php, redirect, exec

I am creating an sms marketing software in php... I need to know some code/suggestion. how i can resolve this issue ? Like sending sms will take long time to execute but i can't wait for it's response. I need to redirect page to another page from there I can monitor it's status like how much has been send and are remaining.

```
shell_exec($obj_sms->sentSms().' > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
shell_exec($obj_sms->sentSms().' > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
```

Comment: Currently you are dumping the output into /dev/null. You could try dumping the output into a custom python program, that puts the data into a database, and then you could access the database from php

Comment: Do yo have any code example..